# Node.js Arduino RC car Bot

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, arduino-uno, johnny-five

I have converted my wireless RC car into a NodeBot using Arduino Uno, Johnny-Five, KeyPress, Node.js and a bluetooth module. Now i can control the car from laptop using up down and right left keys.
I can control the car from a web interface also.
Now i want to run and control the car from a mobile app using above mentioned technologies, I am unable to figure out how to do that.
Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to control the RC car from a web interface, the simple solution would be to use your mobile-device browser to navigate to said web interface and to control the car from there. In order for this to work you need both the computer that your server is running on and your mobile device connected to the same network(ex. your home wifi). Then you need to find the ip address of your server.

To do this run the terminal and type:

> Windows: `ipconfg` and look for IPv4 address
>
> Mac OS: `ipconfig getifaddr en0`
>
> Linux: `ip addr show`

It should(usually) look something like 192.168.x.x

Once you have the ip address use your mobile browser and navigate to `youripaadress:port`, where the port is the same one on which your node.js server is running on. The whole thing should look something like `192.168.x.x:8080`.

This should open your web interface, and you should be able to control the RC car from a mobile device as long as your node server is running.

Unfortunately if you want to use your mobile as a standalone remote (without having the node.js server running on your computer) you will need to go beyond the "mentioned technologies" and learn native app development. If you choose to do it this way, I would recommend [phonegap](http://phonegap.com), because of it's relative simplicity and cross-platform compatibility.

For more native solutions look into Android of iOS development.

Comment: Thanks Matas I have tried the solution that you mentioned, web page is opening in the mobile device but the request to the server is not reaching, i guess this is because of socket.io doesnot work in mobile browser  do. I know cross platform hybrid mobile app development Phonegap and Phonegap Build, But the question is how to node.js code in a phonegap app ?

Comment: It's working now, there was some error in code.
Thank you very much Matas.
Appreciate a lot. :)

Comment: I'm happy that it's working! As for writing node.js mobile applications, that is not (yet?) possible. However, in phonegap you can access your devices hardware (ex. bluetooth) with simple client-side javascript just like the one in your browser. If your goal is to learn node I would suggest not getting involved with mobile apps, and focusing on websites, APIs and other server-based projects.